# Multi Threading OpencCV's VideoCapture

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, opengl

I am wondering if I can benefit from multi-threading the VideoCapture's stream, I am using OpenGL and OpenCV, and my bottleneck is definetely the getting and setting to texture of my video camera's stream.

```
...This goes in the Render Loop.

// We set our video.
try
{

    cap >> frame;

    if( frame.empty() )
    {

        break;

    }

    else
    {

        image = cvMat2TexInput( frame );

    }

    }

    catch( Exception& e )
    {

        std::cout << e.msg << std::endl;

    }

    if( frame.empty() )
    {

        std::cout << "No luck with the VideoCapture..." << std::endl;

    }

    else
    {

        image = cvMat2TexInput( frame );

    }



    if( image )
    {

        glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, videoWidth, videoHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image );

    }

    else
    {

        std::cout << "Failed to load video texture." << std::endl;

    }

    ...
```

This is the function that returns an unsigned char* for our OpenGL's texture input

```
// Utility function to link OpenCV.
unsigned char* cvMat2TexInput( Mat& img )
{

    cvtColor( img, img, COLOR_BGR2RGB );
    transpose( img, img );
    flip( img, img, 1 );
    flip( img, img, 0 );
    return img.data;

}
```

If it is more performant, how would I go about it? I have tried:

```
// Before main:
void multi( VideoCapture cap, Mat& frame )
{

    try
    {

        cap >> frame;

    }

    catch( Exception& e )
    {

        std::cout << e.msg << std::endl;

    }

}

// In main's render loop:
std::thread t1( multi, cap, std::ref( frame ) );
t1.join();

if( frame.empty() )
{

    std::cout << "No luck with the VideoCapture..." << std::endl;

}

else
{

    image = cvMat2TexInput( frame );

}



if( image )
{

    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, videoWidth, videoHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image );

}

else
{

    std::cout << "Failed to load video texture." << std::endl;

}
```

But I have a 10 FPS decrease. I have also tried to migrate the whole setting of the video from:

```
cap >> frame
```

to:

```
if( image )
{

    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, videoWidth, videoHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image );

}

else
{

    std::cout << "Failed to load video texture." << std::endl;

}
```

Into my multi void function but, I get no output at all if not a huge memory leak. I've also tried having two different loops, one inside the threaded function and the main's render loop, but I get no output at all.

So my questions are actually three:

Can I benefit from multi-threading for this process? If yes, how would I implement it? And another one that is related but that can serve me for other processes, how would I call an unsigned char* by reference? The last one was something I wasn't able to do in my multi-threaded function, I tried something like:

```
void multi( ...., unsigned char*& image ){ ... }
```

and calling it like:

```
std::thread t1( multi, ...., std::ref( image ) )
```

or

```
std::thread t1( multi, ...., image )
```

but only got memory leaks!

Since C++11 I guess the OS won't matter, but I am using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017.

Thanks!

Comment: If you create a thread and then join immediately, what would be the benefit? ideally you should do something like put videocapture in a loop which does for every frame the same capture/processing and sets it in a cv::Mat value. Then from the main thread get the cv::Mat value whenever it is needed and set it to OpenGL. Remember to put it thread safe to avoid problems

Comment: Thanks @api55 but as I mentioned, I already tried to do something like that, but didn't manage to. Could you elaborate a little? Thanks! What I did was to loop in a while loop outside of main, then I called my thread, but although that didn't leak, it didn't pass the video capture to OpenGL.